# Change event in Boostrap3 dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a web application written in Angular4 using ngx-bootstrap. I need to call a file open dialog from a bootstrap dropdown menu. I have found a nice example here on how to make the HTML and CSS so the dropdown looks nice here: [make input look and behave like a link in bootstrap dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200075/make-input-look-and-behave-like-a-link-in-bootstrap-dropdown)

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li dropdown class="btn-group" container="body">
    <a href dropdownToggle (click)="false" role="button" >Desktop&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
        <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let desktop of desktops$ | async">
            <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/{{desktop.$key}}">{{desktop.name}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="childModal.show()" style="cursor:pointer;">New...</a>
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete...</a>
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Share...</a>
        <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="btn-file">
            Add files...<input type="file" (change)="detectFiles($event)" style="cursor:pointer;" />
        </a></li>
        <!--<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/add-files">Add files...</a>-->
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Remove files...</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

To get the file the user selected I have added a (change)="detectFiles($event) to the input, but the function is newer called.

If I move the code:

```
<li><a class="btn-file">
    Add files...<input type="file" (change)="detectFiles($event)" style="cursor:pointer;" />
</a></li>
```

out of the dropdown detectFiles is called as expected.

I found some articles about bootstrap stopping event propagation on dropdowns like this [Twitter bootstrap stop propagation on dropdown open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323066/twitter-bootstrap-stop-propagation-on-dropdown-open) but I cannot really understand the suggested solutions and how they can be applied in an Angular app.

So how can I get the (change) event from within a bootstrap3 dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had copied the HTML dropdown code from ngx-bootstaps v4 documentation. So remove container="body" and it works.